# JAVA Access Bridge version when running java 1.4 in JRE 8

Tags: java, .net, java-access-bridge

If I am not mistaken older versions of Java e.g. Oracle Forms running on 1.4, will still work, when ran in JVM 8.

But my question is related to Java Accessibility. I am struggling to make the Oracle Forms expose its elements. Therefore I am wondering whether it could be that the JRE which is running Oracle Forms 1.4 would require me to have Java Access Bridge for 1.4?

I am not sure how this part works any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/access/enable_and_test.html

In case there are many versions of Java used in the technology stack, it is advisable to just go through them all and disabling different versions.

In my case, unfortunately, the application is built in a way that Accessibility is not supported.